What's the intuition behind the mean square of something that deviates around an average being greater than the square of the mean?
I think I can understand this algebraically but is there a way to see this more intuitively, like understanding why the sum is bigger when the inside is squared compared to when the whole thing is squared? Is there a more visual explanation perhaps?

Is it enough to observe that splitting any value $x$ into two values $x+a$ and $x-a$ (thus preserving the mean) leads to an increase in the expectation of the square, since $\frac12\left[(x+a)^2+(x-a)^2\right] = x^2+a^2 > x^2$ if $a > 0$?

If the mean is zero, it's pretty obvious, isn't it?
